# How can i get original mail content(message) in sieve vacation?

Tags: sieve, sieve-language

I need to get a original content (message) of received email in sieve. I need to write a script to send an reply to all emails. I writed this script below to get an subject of original message, but I also need a message. How I can get this? Is there any way to get content into variable in sieve?

```
require "variables";
require "vacation";

set "subject" "";
if header :matches "subject" "*" {
   set "subject" "${1}";
}

vacation :subject "Re: ${subject}" text:
Thanks for message.

THERE SHOULD BE ORIGINAL MESSAGE
.
;
```